# Meteor reactive tables with FS.Collection

Tags: meteor, collectionfs

I'm struggling to implement reactive tables based on a FS.Collection object. I've tried both aldeed/meteor-tabular and aslagle/reactive-table but both fail because the collection doesn't appear to exist. However, if I subscribe and retrieve fields from the Collection without using a reactive table package then the data displays just fine. What am I missing? It can't be a coincidence that both packages fail to work...

Here's my implementation with the aslagle/reactive-table package...

```
  //template
  <template name="documentTable">
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    {{> reactiveTable settings=settings}}
  {{else}}
    {{> spinner}}
  {{/if}}
  {{#if currentUser}}
    {{> fileUpload}}
  {{/if}}
</template>

//documents js
Template.documents.onCreated( () => {
  p_id = FlowRouter.current().params.id;
  Template.instance().subscribe('documents', p_id);
});

Template.documents.helpers({
  documents: function () {
    return Documents.find();
  },

  settings: function () {
    return {
      collection: documents,
      showFilter: false,
      rowsPerPage: 5,
      showNavigation: auto,
      showRowCount: true,
      fields: ['_id','userId','propertyId','uploadedAt']
    };
  }
});

//collection definition 
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var docStore = new FS.Store.S3("documents", {
    region: "eu-west-1",
    accessKeyId: (Meteor.isServer && !process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ? Meteor.settings.AWSAccessKeyId : null),
    secretAccessKey: (Meteor.isServer && !process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ? Meteor.settings.AWSSecretAccessKey : null),
    bucket: Meteor.isServer && process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET || Meteor.settings.AWSBucket,
    folder: "documents"
  });

  Documents = new FS.Collection("Documents", {
    stores: [docStore],
    filter: {
      allow: {
        contentTypes: ['application/pdf']
      }
    }
  });
}
// end server

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var docStore = new FS.Store.S3("documents");

  Documents = new FS.Collection("Documents", {
    stores: [docStore],
    filter: {
      allow: {
        contentTypes: ['application/pdf']
      }
    }
  });
}
// end client

// allow rules
Documents.allow({
  insert: function(userId) {
    // only allow insert from signed in user
    return userId != null;
  },
  update: function(userId) {
    // only allow update from signed in uesr
    return userId != null;
  },
  download: function() {
    return true;
  },
});
```

In the reactive-table case I'm getting the error that the argument is not an instance of Mongo.Collection, a cursor or an array while with meteor-tabular it fails to start because it encounters a ReferenceError and states that Documents isn't defined.

Anyone any thoughts on this?

Comment: Nobody got any thoughts?? :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm using aslagle/reactive-table with mongo quite well, with a pub/sub model; I don't know what your new FS is? is that a mongo collection?

I have something like this when I use the reactive-table...

```
//on the server
Documents = new Mongo.Collection('documents');

//on the client js
Documents = new Mongo.Collection('documents');

Template.documents.helpers({
   settings: function () {
      return {
      collection: Documents.find(),
      rowsPerPage: 5,
      showFilter: false,
      showNavigation: auto,
      showRowCount: true,
      fields: [
         {key: '_id',
          label: 'ID' },
         {key: 'userId',
          label: 'User#' },
         {key: 'propertyId',
          label: 'Property#' },
         {key: 'uploadedAt',
          label: 'Uploaded' },
         ]
      };
   }
});

//on the client html file
{{> reactiveTable class="table table-bordered table-hover" settings=settings}}
```